# Closest Selector jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to select a value with jquery closest but I'm a newbie and my attempts haven't been successful.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong ? Any help appreciated!

```
<div class="two columns">                              
 <form class="float-right">  
    <input type="hidden" id="show_id" value="329">
    <input type="hidden" id="user_id" value="172">
    <div id="follow-button" class="button small follow-call follow-show float-right">Follow</div> 
  </form>
</div>
<div class="two columns">                          
 <form class="float-right">  
    <input type="hidden" id="show_id" value="389">
    <input type="hidden" id="user_id" value="172">
    <div id="follow-button" class="button small follow-call follow-show float-right">Follow</div> 
  </form>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
 $('.follow-show').bind('click', function() {
        var button = $(this);
        var show_id = button.closest("#show_id").val();
        var user_id = button.closest("#user_id").val();
 });
```

Comment: (a) `.closest` looks for *ancestors*, not siblings (see the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)). (b) IDs must be **unique**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use duplicate id's, You can use class instead,

You need to use `siblings` instead of `closest`

```
var button = $(this);
var show_id = button.siblings("#show_id").val();
var user_id = button.siblings("#user_id").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use same id for 2 elements. Try to chage for class. I used jquery Siblings method to select.

```
<div class="two columns">
 <form class="float-right">  
    <input type="hidden" class="show_id" value="329">
    <input type="hidden" class="user_id" value="172">
    <a id="follow-button" class="button small follow-call follow-show float-right">Follow</a> 
  </form>
</div>

<div class="two columns">
 <form class="float-right">  
    <input type="hidden" class="show_id" value="330">
    <input type="hidden" class="user_id" value="173">
    <a id="follow-button" class="button small follow-call follow-show float-right">Follow</a> 
  </form>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$('.follow-show').bind('click', function() {

        var button = $(this);
        var show_id = button.siblings(".show_id").val();
        var user_id = button.siblings(".user_id").val();

        alert(show_id);
        alert(user_id);
});
```

Here the sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Closest always works for parent elements only. It will not select closest child element.
Siblings always check the downward elements.

```
<div id="div1">Nitin </div>
<ul class="level-3">
    <li class="item-1">1</li>
    <li class="item-2">2</li>
    <li class="item-3">3</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.level-3').closest('#div1').css('background-color', 'red');
//Select nothing

$('.item-1').closest('li').css('background-color', 'red');
//Mark 1 as red

$('.item-1').closest('ul').css('background-color', 'red');
//Mark <ul class="level-3"> as red.

$('.item-1').siblings('li').css('background-color', 'green');
//Mark 2 and 3 as green`
```